# Cumulative plot in R - One line showing thicker than others

Tags: r, line, cumulative-distribution-function

I wrote the below code to create this cumulative plot but for some reason, the green line is showing thicker than the other lines on the plot.

[image]

Below is the code I am using:

```
plot(ecdf(data1[data1$Group=="0-25",]$Change_in_PM2.5),
     xlim=c(-1,1),
     xlab="ΔPM2.5 (µg/m³)",
     ylab="Cumulative Proportion",
     main="ΔPM2.5 (µg/m³) distribution across Minority rate ranges",
     col="orange")
lines(ecdf(data1[data1$Group=="25-50",]$Change_in_PM2.5),
      col="#CC6666")
lines(ecdf(data1[data1$Group=="50-75",]$Change_in_PM2.5),
      col="#9999CC")
lines(ecdf(data1[data1$Group=="75-100",]$Change_in_PM2.5),
      col="#66CC99")

abline(v=0, col="black", lty=2, lwd=1)
legend(x = c(0.8, 1), y = c(0, 0.45), 
       legend=c("0-25","25-50","50-75","75-100"),  # text in the legend
       cex = 0.77, x.intersp = 0.3, y.intersp = 0.3,
       col=c("orange", "#CC6666", "#9999CC", "#66CC99"),  # point colors
       pch=15,bty="n")  # specify the point type to be a square
```

Any idea why this would be the case?

Sample data looks like this:

[image]

**Dput output:**

structure(list(Minority_rate = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.41, 0, 0, 0, 0.5
), Change_in_PM2.5 = c(-0.2465, -0.2424, -0.2332, -0.2313, -0.224,
-0.2142, -0.2056, -0.1947, -0.1911, -0.1865, -0.1859, -0.1761,
-0.1725, -0.1593, -0.1577, -0.1532, -0.1531, -0.1413, -0.1332,
-0.1294, -0.119, -0.1159, -0.1153, -0.0993, -0.0962, -0.499,
-0.0859, -0.0817, -0.0806, -0.4755), Group = structure(c(1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("0-25",
"25-50", "50-75", "75-100"), class = "factor"), Population = c(29308L,
36379L, 29395L, 29582L, 29588L, 23079L, 29546L, 29608L, 75403L,
36379L, 29629L, 36068L, 77297L, 81857L, 29186L, 34215L, 57007L,
36264L, 79050L, 31984L, 24278L, 59723L, 36197L, 21931L, 21257L,
77362L, 36396L, 67234L, 29504L, 186205L), Population_weighted_ChangeinPM2.5 = c(-5.4e-06,
-6.6e-06, -5.13e-06, -5.12e-06, -4.96e-06, -3.7e-06, -4.54e-06,
-4.31e-06, -1.08e-05, -5.07e-06, -4.12e-06, -4.75e-06, -9.97e-06,
-9.75e-06, -3.44e-06, -3.92e-06, -6.53e-06, -3.83e-06, -7.88e-06,
-3.1e-06, -2.16e-06, -5.18e-06, -3.12e-06, -1.63e-06, -1.53e-06,
-2.89e-05, -2.34e-06, -4.11e-06, -1.78e-06, -6.62e-05)), row.names = c(NA,
30L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: It looks like the green line is a series of dots/markers. Can’t explain it and without sample data can’t reproduce it either.

Comment: But the green line is set up similar to the other lines.

Comment: Its not allowing me to add the csv file. But I just added a screenshot of the sample data in the description.

Comment: Paste in the output of the `dput(head(data1, 30))` this will be 30 rows from your data frame.  Then it will be easier to cut and paste the data.

Comment: You can share your data with the `dput` function: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg?t=35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you originally created the above plot, since the default option just plots markers.
It seems that adding the "vertical=TRUE" and "do.points = FALSE" to the plot statements creates the lines which you are looking for.

Try this:

```
plot(ecdf(data1[data1$Group=="0-25",]$Change_in_PM2.5),
     xlim=c(-1,1),
     xlab="ΔPM2.5 (µg/m³)",
     ylab="Cumulative Proportion",
     main="ΔPM2.5 (µg/m³) distribution across Minority rate ranges",
     col="orange", verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE)
lines(ecdf(data1[data1$Group=="25-50",]$Change_in_PM2.5),
      col="#CC6666", verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE)
lines(ecdf(data1[data1$Group=="50-75",]$Change_in_PM2.5),
      col="#9999CC", verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE)
lines(ecdf(data1[data1$Group=="75-100",]$Change_in_PM2.5),
      col="#66CC99", verticals = TRUE, do.points = FALSE)

abline(v=0, col="black", lty=2, lwd=1)
legend(x = c(0.8, 1), y = c(0, 0.45), 
       legend=c("0-25","25-50","50-75","75-100"),  # text in the legend
       cex = 0.9, x.intersp = 0.3, y.intersp = 0.99,
       col=c("orange", "#CC6666", "#9999CC", "#66CC99"),  # point colors
       pch=19,bty="n")  # specify the point type to be a square
```